# Angular library as a dependency with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I've an Angular component which I want to make available to be imported by other projects as a dependency. For certain reasons I can´t use npm and I'm using git as a private repository.

At the moment I'm doing some testing with a really dummy component, so in the project where I developed the component I'm using webpack to generate the js files, so my /dist folder has something like this:

```
dummy-component.js
package.json
```

Inside dummy-component.js I have my bundled files, which are basically

```
dummy.module.ts
/dummy
  dummy.component.ts
  dummy.component.scss
  dummy.component.html
```

So the contents of this /dist file are pushed into a `dummy-dist` repository and imported by a different project as a dependency using

```
"my-dummy-component": "git+https://.../_git/dummy-dist"
```

And this is imported nicely into my /node_modules folder (that is, the js file and the package.json).

Then I try to use it in my app.module.ts, as in

```
...
import { DummyModule } from 'my-dummy-component';
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    DummyModule
  ],
...
```

But when I try to start the project I get an error from webpack

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
(13,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'my-dummy-component'.
```

That exists within my node_modules folder, so I'm guessing I'm missing some other stuff. What is it? I tried using an index.js also inside /node_modules that exports the module, but with no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: After reading the first link provided by @Pavlo in the comments I managed to generate now the definition types also.
Now the contents of my /dist folder are

```
dist/
  dist/
    dummy/
      dummy.component.d.ts
    dummy.module.d.ts
  dummy.bundle.js
  dummy.bundle.js.map
  package.json
```

And in my package.json

```
    "name": "dummy",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "main": "dummy.bundle.js",
    "module": "dummy.bundle.js",
    "types": "dummy.module.d.ts",
    "peerDependencies": {
      ..
    },
    "private": true
  }
```

Now webpack works fine but when I load the page I get an error in the console

```
Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
    at Error.ZoneAwareError
```

Comment: can you upload your `'my-dummy-component'` somewhere? what is webpack configuration that packaged it?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a re-usable Angular library is not as straightforward as building an Angular application with Webpack. You need to build it in a special way to preserve the ES2015 modules (import/export statements), create TypeScript definition files and do AOT compilation of the components.

Please see the following guide for the details on how to do that exactly: http://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/21/distributing-an-angular-library-aot-ngc-types/

Also, you can use a template to get started with the basic setup, like this one: https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library

Comment: Thanks @Pavlo, I understand it's not the same. I got it all working with ngs only to realize that I needed some kind of bundler to deal with external html templates and scss files, so I used webpack, but that kind of messed everything as it only generates a bundler, no metadata.json or anything